# Contacts which are on your app and in your phone director are same

Tags: ios, objective-c

How would i search those contacts which are registered in your app and that exist in your contact List?

Answer (score 2):

1. Fetch your Register user list.
2. Fetch your contact list.
   http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-import-contact-address-book/
3. compare your contacts phone number or email id with your register
   users list.

Comment: is this should be done on app side?like fetch all the registered number from server than compare on your app side using for loop directly?

Comment: you can do it both the way but if you upload your contacts on server then each time on contact update or add you need to upload to server. So I  prefer to fetch register user list. If answer work pls +1 ;)